# Printing the wrong value when evaluating postfix expressions

Tags: c

I wrote a program which is used to evaluate postfix expression, I am not getting any compiler error/warnings but I am not getting the correct output, which probably means the issue is with the calculation but I don't know where.

My Code:

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

#define MAX 20
char s[MAX], top = 0;

void main() {
    char postfix[MAX], ch;
    int i, op1, op2, res;
    clrscr();
    printf("\n\t\t program to evaluate postfix expression");
    printf("\n\t\t.......");
    printf("\n enter the postfix expression:\n");
    scanf("%s", &postfix);
    for (i = 0; i < strlen(postfix); i++) {
        ch = postfix[i];
        if (isdigit(ch))
            push(ch = '0');
        else {
            op2 = pop();
            op1 = pop();
            switch (ch) {
              case '+':
                res = op1 + op2;
                break;
              case '-':
                res = op1 - op2;
                break;
              case '*':
                res = op1 * op2;
                break;
              case '/':
                res = op1 / op2;
                break;
              case '^':
                res = pow(op1, op2);
                break;
              default:
                printf("invalid choice");
            }
            push(res);
        }
    }
    printf("result of above expression is:%d\n", pop());
    getch();
}
push(int element) {
    ++top;
    s[top] = element;
}
int pop() {
    int element;
    element = s[top];
    --top;
    return (element);
}
```

Comment: A program successfully compiling just means it *can* run; it doesn't necessarily mean it will do the right thing when it runs.

Comment: You need to show the provided input, the desired result and the actual output.

Comment: Sanjay kumar, `scanf("%s", & postfix);` is subject to buffer overrun.  Use a width limit.

Comment: FWIW, do not use `pow` for integer calculations.

Comment: This program should also give you a bunch of warnings, for example about implicitly declared `push` and `pop`, so you can't say it is "successfully compiling". Such a warnings should be treated as errors.

Comment: I'm not sure what `push(ch = '0');` is trying to do here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should fix the typo and change `push(ch = '0');` to

```
    push(ch - '0');
```

`ch` is a character, `isdigit(ch)`, or better `isdigit((unsigned char)ch)` tells you it is a digit, `ch` - '0'`is the digit value, a number in the range`0`to`9`.

Your code `ch = '0'` stores the digit `'0'` into `ch` and pushes this value, which is the character code or `0` on your system, 48 in ASCII.

Comment: Ah, I was confused by what he was trying to do with that.  I guess he is trying to modify by the 0 char offset?

Comment: Thanks @chqrlie, that is what I was thinking although didn't articulate well.  The update is helpful for those of us that largely have relied on higher level functions to do this :D